# Algorithm complexity with iterations. Is it logarithmic or exponential?

Tags: c, time-complexity

If I have the following algorithm

```
for (i = 1; i <= 4 * n; i = i * 4) {
   for (k = 1; k < 1000; k = 2 * k) {
       print(k);
   }
   print(i);
}
```

how can  I calculate its complexity?
I only understand that for one iteration of `for(i=1; i≤4n; i=i*4)`, the line with `print(i)` is O(1), and for one iteration of `for(k=1; k<1000; k=2*k)`, the line with `print(k)` is O(1).

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Comment: If you search on the phrase "determine computational complexity" or any [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it) on SO, you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the inner loop:

```
for(k=1; k<1000; k=2*k) {
    print(k);
}
```

That loop is constant time, because there are no free variables. It's always going to call `print` exactly 9 times, for `k ∈ {1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512}`.

The outer loop is O(log n), because it will execute ⌊log₄ 4n⌋ times.

Overall, the program fragment you posted (if we add the final closing brace you omitted) is O(log n).